# VBA: show intellisense without pressing Ctrl+Space?

Tags: vba, intellisense

I've had a good search if this is possible and I doubt it but can anyone confirm: is there any way to have the IDE provide intellisense in the same way as say Visual Studio in the .Net family i.e. it's automatic, no need to press Ctrl+Space for a new item?

The object.period functionality is fine but it would be great if it could for example predict which of your variables you want next, so If I dim a recordset called rst and start typing "Set" then a list of declared objects would show, including rst, again, just like in .Net. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you writing the VBa? In VS, Excel, Notepad? I assume Excel, but need to make sure

Comment: Supposing you use VBA in any office product the answer is probably no. (If that would be an opportunity I think it would have been switched on by default).

Comment: @ Dave, sorry yes I was referring to the IDEs in Excel, Access and the like.

Comment: @ Máté, yeah, figures

Comment: Visual Studio is *a lot* more advanced than VBE. You can only get intellisense for the VBA Object Model, nothing user defined unless it's a class.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this functionality doesn't exist (perfectly) within the native VBA IDE.

Some people report checking "Auto List Members" in Tools > Options helps.